# Windows 10 Store keeps Crashing

Tags: windows

I upgraded to Windows 10 today and every time I open the store it says "The server stumbled." I tried opening it by clicking on the buy now button on the online store, but it just crashes again. I can't open it no matter what i do How do i fix this?

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC to m verify your system integrity.

Comment: http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-general-discussion/370214-windows-10-store-crashes-everytime-server-stumbled.html "I turned off auto set time. Changed time. Opened store, opened with 'server stumbled' error. Changed time to auto, opened store and worked. "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Worked!!! It seemed pretty mediocre thing to really work but just do this: I followed DavidPostill steps and it does work!

"1. I turned off auto set time.

"2. Changed time.

"3. Opened store and it opened with 'server stumbled' error. then...

"4. Changed time to auto, opened store and worked."

Though it still crashes sometimes but pickups once you click retry. Sure fix!

Comment: For me I only turn the auto set timer off and on and the store started to work again !